# resposive layout of wordpress template

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Absolutely pulling my hair out on this one as I don't know much about jquery. There seems to be no black and white solution offered anywhere.

Basically, I am trying to create a fluid and responsive portfolio. The width of the column is set to 390px but I want it to be smaller (320px) for mobile devises with screens < 480px. Could anyone help me with this one please

Here is the code

```
(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function

var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(window).load(function(){

  // Masonry.js
  var $container = $('#posts');

  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: 390,
      isFitWidth: true
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: I would suggest NOT using jQuery for this, and instead use CSS Media Queries.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: This is the wrong way to do a responsive website. You should set up CSS Media Queries to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media (max-width: 481px) {
        .box{
            width:100%;
            max-width:320px;
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you really want to use JavaScript then have a look at [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 481px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
    var myBox = document.querySelector(".box");
    myBox.style.width = "320px";
    /*****JQUERY
     var styles = {
          width:320px
     };
    $(".box").css(styles);
    ****/
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But what if I really want to use jquery?

Comment: sorry but it looks like it doesn't work. where exactly should i put this piece of code? thanks

Comment: javascrpit goes in the Footer and wrap it in a `<script>` tag if you want to use css media queries add it to your `style.css`